# Limitar casas decimais - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

Opaa!

Fiz um select de uma tabela que me retorna o valor de um livro com uma porcentagem de ajuste, tanto negativo quanto positivo. Porém está me retornando um valor com várias casas decimais, e gostaria de limitar a somente 2 casas decimais. Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comando select utilizado, nesse exemplo utilizei 10%:

```
select
liv_titulo, liv_preco as preco_atual,
liv_preco + (liv_preco / 100 * 10) as preco_adicao,
liv_preco - (liv_preco / 100 * 10) as preco_subtracao
from livro
```

O retorno do comando ficou dessa maneira:

```
liv_titulo              preco_atual  preco_adicao  preco_subtracao
Engenharia de Software  55.00        60.500000     49.500000
Engenharia de software  78.01        85.811000     70.209000
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
liv_titulo              preco_atual  preco_adicao  preco_subtracao
Engenharia de Software  55.00        60.50         49.50
Engenharia de software  78.01        85.81         70.20
```

Comment: Tens aqui vários exemplos, dependendo da versão. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito simples é este:

```
select
liv_titulo, liv_preco as preco_atual,
CONVERT(DEC(10,2), liv_preco + (liv_preco / 100 * 10)) as preco_adicao,
CONVERT(DEC(10,2), liv_preco - (liv_preco / 100 * 10)) as preco_subtracao
from livro
```

Poderá usar o CAST também.

```
CAST(CAMPO AS NUMERIC(10,2))
```

O 10 significa o número de casas decimais, se o número possuir mais de 10 casas ele irá ocasionar erro de estouro. O 2 significa o número de casas após a virgula.

Answer (score -2):

```html
SELECT
NO_MUNICIPIO_ESC,
SG_UF_ESC,
SG_UF_ESC||"-"||NO_MUNICIPIO_ESC AS Estado_Municipio,
count(*) as Total_Inscricoes,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP1+NU_NOTA_COMP2+NU_NOTA_COMP3+NU_NOTA_COMP4+NU_NOTA_COMP5+NU_NOTA_REDACAO))||.0/10 AS NotaGlobal,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_REDACAO))||.0/10 As Media_Redacao,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP1+NU_NOTA_COMP2+NU_NOTA_COMP3+NU_NOTA_COMP4+NU_NOTA_COMP5))||.0/10 AS MediaGeral_NotaObjetiva,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP1))||.0/10 AS Media_NOTA_01,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP2))||.0/10 AS Media_NOTA_02,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP3))||.0/10 AS Media_NOTA_03,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP4))||.0/10 AS Media_NOTA_04,
printf("%.f", AVG (NU_NOTA_COMP5))||.0/10 AS Media_NOTA_05

FROM "MICRODADOS_ENEM_2021"
WHERE SG_UF_ESC="TO"

Group by Estado_Municipio
Having Total_Inscricoes>50
Order by NotaGlobal
```

Solução para o SQLITE retirar as casas decimais.